# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined - Ionic 4 - Windows only

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've come across an error that I have no idea how it's come about, but it is blocking me to develop on a PC... I can build my app on a Mac, but when I try on a Windows box it fails with.

> cordova build android --stacktrace
>
> config file undefined requested for changes not found at 
>   platforms\android\undefined, ignoring config file undefined requested for changes not found at
>   platforms\android\undefined, ignoring
>
> The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type
>   string. Received type undefined
>
> at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)

That's even on a clean Windows machine cloned from GIT.

$ ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.21
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.20
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v12.14.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10

---

```
{
  "name": "xyz1",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "author": "Keni Barwick",
  "homepage": "https://barwick.net/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/health": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.7",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-exitapp2": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-health": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-res": "^0.8.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "kr.co.joycorp.cordova.exitapp": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.6.0",
    "npm": "^6.13.4",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-health": {
        "HEALTH_READ_PERMISSION": "App needs read access",
        "HEALTH_WRITE_PERMISSION": "App needs write access",
        "GMS_VERSION": "16.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "kr.co.joycorp.cordova.exitapp": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "browserslist": []
  }
}
```

---

I've updated all plugin's that show as red in npm outdated, checked lots of Stacks for answers but to no avail...

Comment: Is there a longer stack trace with the error?  You will have to dive in to find out which path is wrong and where it's coming from.  It looks to me like whatever is supposed to be setting `platforms\android\xxx` to point to some config file is goofing up so it can't find your config file and perhaps that's why the path ends up wrong.

Comment: Dig in this post it might help you: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1082

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

I knew as soon as I created a post I'd find the answer lol

So it turns out the issue was in the config.xml and specifically the following;

```
<config-file parent="NSHealthShareUsageDescription" platform="ios">
    <string>App needs read access</string>
</config-file>
<config-file parent="NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription" platform="ios">
    <string>App needs write access</string>
</config-file>
```

I removed the above, I was attempting to understand why I was gaining the following warning;

```
config file undefined requested for changes not found at platforms\android\undefined, ignoring
```

Once I removed it I was able to get passed the Path error... Odd right?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing:

```
<config-file
```

to

```
<gap:config-file
```

resolved the issue.

EDIT:
Got another app, another case.
I had to add "target" attribute to config-file.
Example:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
```

Also, if you got a project prepared for PhoneGapBuild and now you need to compile it yourself, remember to set your config under "platform" to diferentiate platform settings.
Example:

```
<plaform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
```